# Demolish planks building with particles

Tags: physics

I want to demolish the planks building applied with physics, use with particles system like bullet physics.
I spend more than one weak with particles system.
and I can't find anything useful.
please help me.

Comment: Can you please include screenshots of what you have and what you want to do? Also add more details.

Comment: do you want the planks to fall like dominoes or do you want bullet holes?

Comment: I think you may be confusing [particles](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/introduction.html) with [rigid body physics](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/rigid_body/introduction.html). Bullet physics would be rigid body.